# If I wanted to make a JavaFX application, but then wanted to add dependencies (like we do with Gradle) how do I do that?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, javafx

So when we create a new Gradle project in IntelliJ, I can obviously add the dependencies I wish to use as a build.gradle file is added and I can add them all in there.

[image]

Now when I create a JavaFX file, they aren't there...

[image]

so how do I go about adding dependencies?

Comment: You could just create a gradle project and add the javafx library.

Comment: Just create a gradle project and start creating JavaFX related files into it.

Comment: We need some details - do you mean that after creating a file, build.gradle disappears or what?

Comment: @Alexiy - Long story short, I've made an application where I have all the programmatic side of it working (e.g. all the code working) and have testing it through JUnit, but now I'd like to add a UI to it, in IntelliJ i've made a new package and called it "UI" and added a new GUI Form in there, but realised that the GUI page does not work in the same way as the Netbeans GUI builder. - I discovered that its worth my while learning about JavaFX for UI, the problem I have is this...

Comment: @Alexiy In the program I have (and I know that Java now has a better Time class to use) used joda-time and added it as a dependency in the build.gradle file as I setup the original program to include one. Now when I setup a JavaFX project there is no build.gradle file so I cannot add the dependency (from how I've learnt through gradle) to my project (same as how you would add a third party library in Android Studio), my other confusion is, is JavaFX just there so I can make a UI an then I add this onto another project I've originally made? Or do I make the whole program in JavaFX?

Comment: I see, so you created a project from menu 'File>New>Project>Javafx'? If so, then you need to create a new Gradle project instead. The Javafx library is a part of JDK so it will be available any way.

Comment: @Alexiy So my current project is a Gradle project, so I'll be able to create a JavaFX UI? I just need to add in the FXML and resources folder?

Comment: Yes, you can use Fxml and/or you can make your UI programmatically.